# Optimal way to define the correct size of a SVG image

Tags: svg, dart

When creating a SVG image you have to set width,height and position otherwise it will not be rendered.
How do I read them from the original image?
Using Dart I first load the html image and after it's loaded I get the size and then define the SVG image and use the info I got before. This is a bit cumbersome and I wondered if there is another way.

The dart code looks like this:

```
ImageElement img = new ImageElement(src:'2.jpg'); //401x600
img.onLoad.listen((e) {
  svg.ImageElement image = new svg.ImageElement();
  image.setAttribute('x', '0');
  image.setAttribute('y', '0');
  image.setAttribute('width', img.width.toString());
  image.setAttribute('height', img.height.toString());
  image.getNamespacedAttributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')['href'] = '2.jpg';

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems not to be a more convenient method (also not in JavaScript except when you use jQuery or another framework that includes methods for this).
Just create a method yourself and reuse that method for each image you load.